# Pulling all data from a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

tl:dr - I have a code that can work but want to make it better by pulling everything from column E into 1 message (including header)

---

I am trying to get the output of a singular column to post to Discord - Here I have the script creating a message in a blank column and looking at the next empty line

```
function postFromSpreadsheet(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName ("Responses")

  const messageCell = ws.getRange(ws.getMaxRows(),152).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).offset(1,-147)

  const currentMessage = messageCell.getValue()

  if(currentMessage == "") return

  postToDiscord(currentMessage)

  messageCell.offset(0,147).setValue("posted")
```

I could do this but would need to loop it

Or

I am trying to take all the data from column 5 (E) and posting it as one message

I have the discord message posting current message and a if statement to stop once the column I am currently using says posted

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user three times. I will remove [tag:discord] because this question doesn't require any knowledge or skill specific to Discord. On the other hand, I'm adding [tag:javascript] because the question is about writing a function using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To combine all messages into one long message, use `Range.getDisplayValues()` and `Array.join()`. To weed out blanks, use `Array.filter(String)`. To set new statuses, use `Array.forEach()`.

Alternatively, to post each message *separately*, put `postToDiscord()` inside the `forEach()` loop.

Finally, to save the new statuses, use `Range.setValues()`, like this:

```
function postFromSpreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
  const messages = sheet.getRange('E1:E').getDisplayValues().flat();
  const statusCells = sheet.getRange('EV1:EV');
  const statuses = statusCells.getValues();

  // post one long message
  const longMessage = messages
    .filter(String)
    .join('\n');
  postToDiscord(longMessage);
  messages.forEach((message, index) => {
    if (message) {
      statuses[index] = ['posted'];
    }
  });
  statusCells.setValues(statuses);

  // another option: post each non-blank message separately
  messages.forEach((message, index) => {
    if (message) {
      postToDiscord(message);
      statuses[index] = ['posted'];
    }
  });
  statusCells.setValues(statuses);
}
```